# Firefox text align center not working with monospace fonts

Tags: html, css, firefox, text-alignment

For some reason Firefox is not center aligning the text on monospace fonts properly (but only large font-sizes). Testing Firefox 32 on Mavericks.

See [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8jzfyphk/2/). Any ideas?

```
<div class="courier">The quick fox centered
</div>
<div class="arial">The quick fox centered
</div>

body {
        font-size: 100pt;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

div {
    width: 100%;
}

.arial {
    font-family: Arial
}
.courier {
       font-family: Courier;
}
```

Comment: it looks centered for me on Firefox Windows 7 and Ubuntu

Comment: Having the same problem, latest Firefox stable on Mavericks. Weird. The word "centered" is centered and "Quick fox" is not. [Fiddle with background to highlight this](http://jsfiddle.net/dL44u1s9/)

Comment: Yeah I'm having the exact same problem. Really weird. If you reduce the font-size the issues goes away [see JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dL44u1s9/8/) I really don't know what is going on  @misterManSam

Answer (score 4):

Try this one

```
text-align:-moz-center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since each div is rendered differently you are getting different center positioning. If you want both the divs to be centered accordingly wrap them inside a div and change the style accordingly. Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jzfyphk/4/)

```
#wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Still not looking right in Mozilla. I've attached a screenshot from your JSFiddle. The Arial div is perfectly centered, but the Courier div looks messed up. [Image Link](http://imgur.com/jaaHsbJ)  @learningloop